# Does Stack Overflow need tips for each part?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

I think we need a list of tips, tips being something that we didn't know about a subject. It could be some function in Rails or Ruby or Python, not problems we had!

1. For example: an new rails developer wants to change a string like "an_example_here" to "anExampleHere", but he doesn't know that rails has a function named "camlize", he does it in another way...
2. Tips like a wiki, but it doesn't mean it must be correct, nothing is always correct, good pratice always changes, right?
3. Tips not used to share funny things, it shares some way for newer
4. Parts like tips for ruby, tips for python and so on
5. It may be a simple way to find what a newer need, not to ask a question, it's a waste of time

Comment: You might want to be a bit more clear on what it is your proposing. And example "tip" might help to illustrate your idea. And that sounds like something that should go into a tag wiki?

Comment: No, *I* don't think we do. Since you didn't give us much in the way of motivation, that's all I can say in response, really. Why do *you* think we do, what would the benefits be, how would we curate such lists?

Comment: You can already create a self-answered question, where you post both the question and the answer in one go. That already gives you the option to introduce others to some interesting solution you found. How would tips fill a need that that feature doesn't give you?

Comment: What do you mean by "each part"?

Comment: please check update

Comment: @user2515401 your update really didn't define "part".  What is a "part".

Answer (score 2):

I think there are two major problems with this:

- Who is writing the tips? Who is assuring that the tips are correct? That they can be considered good practice? Useful? You get the idea.
- Tips may distract from the content you are looking for; likely with information that you already know, or don't care about.

On the upside however: wait, I can't see one.

Comment: please check update